# How can I pass in a parameter to use in an order by sql clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Using PHP/MySQL, how can I place an order by SQL clause?

This syntax isn't working:

```
$diplayquery = sprintf("
  SELECT *
  FROM  user_urls 
  WHERE user_id='%s' 
  ORDER BY total_count",
    mysql_real_escape_string($iduse) );

$diplayqueryout = mysql_query($diplayquery);
```

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking here...

Comment: Often, with posted code, the questioner indicates what has gone wrong, with relevant error messages, as well as what they are trying to accomplish with their code.  I would suggest doing that.

Answer (score 3):

in **SQL** , the `order by` Clause is written like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE condition ORDER BY FieldName [ ASC | DESC ] ;
```

**Example :**

```
SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY first_name ASC;
```

This will select all students and order them by first_name ( ascending ).

So in your case, you should make sure that your query doesn't return one row, because you are testing on the `user_id` which may be **unique**. To make sure of your request, try to execute it on your **PHPMyAdmin**, and see if it returns a result or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inherently wrong with your SQL syntax, however, there are a few aspects of your approach that leave something to be desired.

Foremost, to your error. Since you didn't mention any specific error, I can only assume that the column by which you are attempting to order does not exist in the `user_urls` table. Assuming the ID of "1":

```
SELECT * FROM user_urls WHERE user_id=1 ORDER BY total_count
```

...IS valid sql, as long as the `total_count` column exists. Check out the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

The second issue I see here is your use of sprintf with the classic `mysql_` PHP database functions. If you'd like to use value substitution like that, without having to bother with calling an escape function on each value, you'd be much better served using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). Check out that page for info and examples. If you aren't going to use PDO, there is no reason for your elaborate string concatenation (definitely no advantage to doing it this way), rather, a direct approach would be equally efficient, safe, and surely more clear:

```
$diplayquery = '
    SELECT 
        column1,
        column2,
        column3 
    FROM 
        user_urls 
    WHERE 
        user_id='.mysql_real_escape_string($iduse).' 
    ORDER BY 
        total_count
';
$diplayqueryout = mysql_query($diplayquery);
```

Finally, I suggest that you not use the `SELECT *` approach. It is regarded as better practice to explicitly name the columns that you are fetching from the database, that way your result set isn't a "magical" collection of who-knows what fields. Instead of `SELECT *`, use `SELECT columnName1, columnName2, etc`, as demonstrated in the code sample above.

Comment: can I use the order by clause with sprintf() ?     $diplayquery = sprintf("select total_count,url
from  user_urls 
    WHERE user_id='%s' 
 order by total_count",
    mysql_real_escape_string($iduse) );

Comment: Yes; as I said, there is nothing wrong with your SQL syntax. The SQL server doesn't care what method you use to build a query, it will attempt to execute whatever you hand it (even if it isn't valid). Whether you used `sprintf` or `rand()`, the SQL server is truly indifferent, as long as the syntax is correct you'll get a result. The remainder of my answer is advice unrelated to the ORDER BY issue you're having.